# Android Pocket app design layout

Tags: android, layout

I'm very keen to know which layout format using "**pocket**" apps as follow. I'd like to know how to step by step layout usage just like this apps.

[image]

Comment: Checkout MultiRowListAdapter https://github.com/umano/MultiItemRowListAdapter Which might give you some help.

Comment: @GrIsHu can you post as answer? I'll have to mark as correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [MultiRowListAdapter](https://github.com/umano/MultiItemRowListAdapter) which allows you to very quickly make your ListViews and ListActivities look amazing. It might give you some help.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the UI it seems **Fragments** are used with **ActionBarSherlock**.

Create your required fragments and include in this template.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f5f5f5"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffbf00" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#fff" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#37c100" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#37c100" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffbf00" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#fff" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="#ffbf00" >
            </LinearLayout>



            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#37c100" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#37c100" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#ffbf00" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#fff" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Leave it about ActionBar. Please let me know how to complete this layout style with so many blocks.

Comment: Have you heard of include block in a UI ? Just include fragments in UI.

Comment: Updated answer, check now.

Comment: If so, need to use so many cursors for each layout. What I mean is dynamically create view like GridLayout.